# Performance issues on Dataflow batch loads using Apache Beam

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I was doing a performance benchmarking of dataflow batch loads and found that the loads were just too slow when compared against the same loads on Bigquery command line tool.

The file size was around 20 MB with millions of records. I tried different machine types and got the best load performance on `n1-highmem-4` with the approx load time of 8 minutes in loading the target BQ table.

When the same table load was applied by running BQ command on the command-line utility, it hardly took 2 minutes to process and load the same volume of data.
Any insights about this poor load performance using Dataflow jobs? How to improve the performance to make it comparable to BQ command line utility?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, a few minutes are being spent on starting and shutting down VMs. If you're doing something that can directly be done using BQ CLI, then using Dataflow for that purpose is likely overkill. However, you can update your question with more details (e.g. your code and the Dataflow job id) - maybe there's something else inefficient going on.

Comment: Thank you @jkff. I will share more details (Job IDs &  snippets) once in office after the weekends. However I can explain the exact process. First of all my code reads the data from `Text/Avro` file using `TextIO/AvroIO.read()`. Then I compare the existing records in the table and new entries in the PCollection based on some keys to have the new list of elements in the table as the part of `Upsert` process. After this process it simply pushes the new PCollection of `TableRows` in the target table using `BigqueryIO.write()`. This is the three step process I'm trying to implement in Dataflow.

Comment: Please find the job ID : `2017-11-24_03_41_00-13093050104159263095` to help me analysing the latency problem I'm facing. This was the job ID for the same job which took 16 minutes to complete. Earlier using the same machine type my job was completed in 8 minutes. The job ID for the same is `2017-11-24_02_47_19-15366595440306710005`.

Comment: The job seems to include a "Read configuration" step that takes a majority of the time. Can you include some of your code? Also, did you look at the transform timings in the Dataflow web UI, and at the logs there? They might give a hint as to what's going on.

Comment: Thank you @jkff !!! I also identified the pieces which are taking majority of the time. 'Read Configuration' is the step in which I'm using 'NestedValueProvider' to find runtime value for 'FileName' and by passing that value to a simple 'select' command I'm fetching some configuration values like 'table name', 'schema' etc. This process consists of a `BigqueryIO.read().fromQuery()` operation. Another part where I observed some significant latency was my `Upsert` logic where I'm pulling existing table records, comparing with new records and finally merging the PCollections to load the target.

Comment: By looking at the `Transformation` part over PCollections I think there is nothing unexpected is going on as far as timing in handling transformations is concerned, but 'Read Configuration' is a simple Bigquery read operation. Any insights why it is taking much time? I'll update my question with sample snippet once in office tomorrow.